# React Native listView - Using props into rowData

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native

I have a props. I want to use listView but when I add it all changes.

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={
        (rowData) =>    
        <CardToefl
            onPress={() => Actions.questDetay({zamqi: rowData.stept_id})}
            stept={rowData.stept_baslik} 
            descriptionEnglish={rowData.stept_ingdesc}
            descriptionTurkish={rowData.stept_trdesc} 
            myId={rowData.stept_id}
            progreset={this.props.processDetayDeger}
        /> 
    } >
</ListView>
```

I just want to change one. How can I do?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code, especially at `rowData.stept_id`?

Comment: Yes, I try this but I failed.

Comment: Failed how? Are you sure that every `rowData` is unique?